# How to convert date/time field to date value

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components

I am displaying date field on a Lightning component. The Type of that field is Date/Time. But I want to display only date part on the component.

code
 used

v.quote.SubmitDate__c  -->This code is present on the component.

Quote is the Object on Salesforce

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck and how can we assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the [ui:outputDateTime component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputDateTime.htm)?

It has a format attribute that takes:

> A string (pattern letters are defined in java.text.SimpleDateFormat) used to format the date and time of the value attribute.

As best as I can tell from the documentation for [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can use a format like `"yyyy-MM-dd"` to just output the Date.